# Show/hide table rows in jQuery that have already been "filtered" with a show or hide

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table of recordset results that is being filtered by A-Z tabs. So when I click on the letter "A", only the `<tr>`'s that start with the letter A are being shown from the full list. Everything works great, the problem now is that it needs some further filtering.

Now I need it to be filtered between all/active/inactive. I can't seem to figure this out. How to I show hide table rows that have already hidden/shown rows? Here's the code that I'm using for the letter filtering.

```
  $('.but_tab').on('click',function(){
    $('.nav-tabs .active').removeClass('active');

    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

    console.log(tab);

    $('.t_all').hide();
    $('.t_'+tab).show();

    // further filter list based on whether all/active/inactive has the active class...?
    filterResults();

  });

function filterResults(){

    var curFilter = $('.but-filter.active').attr('data-type');

    //?

};
```

Here's what the code for the table rows look like:

```
<tr class="t_all t_A filter-all filter-True">
```

Each row will contain "filter-all" and either a "filter-True" or "filter-False" based on whether it's active or not.

Comment: If you click A, and then click B, is it intended that the filter on A is undone, or that you show both results for A and B?

Comment: let's say that it's currently set to show "Inactive". If i'm viewing the letter "A" and then click on letter "B", it should show me letter B "inactive" until click on "all" which would then show me all of "B"

Comment: I suggest separating your data from your DOM. Basically, have a unique identifier for each row in both the data and the DOM. Filter the data, not the DOM. Then just update the DOM based on the data. Everything gets much easier after that.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by separating DOM and data... can you elaborate a little more please?